# Is there a way to create a database with mongoose that has a username and password?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I'm currently working on a app (dev with electron). I'm using mongoDB and mongoose for my persistant storage but I can't find a way to do something that seem really basic : when creating a database I'd like to add an user and a password to it (I realy search for it, but no way to find anything usable).

I have this need because it's going to be a multi-user app and I definitly don't want an user to know the contents of another user account.

The idea is that once you create an account, the app create a database that has the same username and password of the account. For login, the app try to connect you to the database with your account & password.

I'm working with :

- electron
- HTML / CSS / javascript
- mongoDB
- mongoose

Here is the code that I tested :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connStr = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
mongoose.connect(connStr, {user: 'newUser', password: 'pwd', useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {throw err};
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB");
});
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: password must be a string]
```

However with those, the database is correctly created (but anyone can access it) :

```
user: '', password: ''
```

What I expect is to create a new database with the user name set as "newUser" and the password as "pwd", in that way only with the correct id & password would it be possible to connect to it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: i'd go for an approach where you have one database, one table with users and password list and in each row of data that you have in your db you refer to the id of the user it belongs to. Much better than many different databases!

Comment: That was the initial approach but the thing is that with a unique data base, if for intance you open MongoDB Compas Community you have accss to all the element inside the database (with the hash of the different password, so with little effort you would have access to the account). Even if I set a password in the app, to connect to the DB I'll need to make the username and password appear in the code and since it's coded in JS, it's client side, so they will have acces to it quite easely :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not but I ran a mongo service using docker and then connected mongoose to it with the following code

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/MyDB?authSource=admin', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connection successful'))
.catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB:‌', err));
```

this is equivalent to

mongo --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --port 27017

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just test it. With an existing database that is set with an user & password it work perfectly fine. However my issue is that I'd like to create a DB thanks to JS with username & password authentification. If what you sugested is used without an existing DB (or user & pwd), I got the same error as describe previously.